# Swift: I am getting error in firebase mobile authentication

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

error when call

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(txtmobile.text!) { (verificationID, error) in
    if error != nil {
          Model.shared.showAlert(msg: (error?.localizedDescription)!, vc: self)
          return
    }
}
```

> error is "Token mismatch"

Comment: Explain with details.

Comment: can you refer doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

Comment: Are you adding a device token?

Comment: yes bro add proper, also test that work proper. notification come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> first configure your project to firebase
>
> in authentication section in signing method phone enable
>
> download info playlist  and add in project by drag and drop
>
> install required pod

app delegate in add

```
     import Firebase
     import FirebaseAuthUI

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
          FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
```

in view controller you need to verify phone number

```
          import FirebaseAuth
                import FirebaseAuthUI
                import FirebasePhoneAuthUI

         class viewController: UIviewcontroller,FUIAuthDelegate {
             override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()

                  FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.delegate = self
                  let phoneProvider = FUIPhoneAuth.init(authUI: FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!)
                  FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.providers = [phoneProvider]
                  phoneProvider.signIn(withPresenting: self, phoneNumber: nil)
            }
            func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?) {
            if let user = user {
            print("I'm logged in")
            }
            else {
               print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Something went wrong")
            }
      }
```

Comment: what is the problem??

Comment: `PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) {`  the new version on the firebase doc is causing my app to crash. If I remove the `uiDelegate: nil` it works!?

Comment: `PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(self.phoneNumberTextField.text!, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
                
                if let error = error {
     
                    print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                    
                }
                
                UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "enterVerificationCode", sender: self)  
            }`